# Call a stored procedure from a column in table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hope someone can help me with this.  I've got a table that will hold stored procedure calls along with the priority of those calls and stored procedure that reads this table and executes the procedures.

The query like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = SELECT TOP 1 procColumn FROM ProcRequest WHERE Status = 'NotRan' ORDER BY Priority, TimeSubmitted
EXEC @sql
```

When I execute the sql I get the following error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 3
>   Could not find stored procedure 'dev.dbo.uspProc1 10,'2013-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00''

The procedure exists and if I copy the procedure call from the column in the table and execute it, it runs.

Procedure call looks like this:

```
dev.dbo.uspProc1 10,'2013-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
select top 1 @sql = procColumn from ProcRequest where Status = 'NotRan' order by Priority, TimeSubmitted
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: No worries @denimknight :)